# How to set proxy in config for protector

Tags: protractor

I am using protector with angular 4, when i run e2e test it failed to download some dependency from network as it blocked within my org proxy.

I tried to set proxy in protractor.conf.js, but it did not work for me.

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'proxy': {
  'proxyType': 'manual',
  'httpProxy': 'http://ptx.proxy.corp.sopra:8080'
}
```

below error I'm getting when run ng e2e

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.204.144:443
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

Can someone please tell me how to use the proxy within in.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way around to set the proxy, I set up proxy in system environment variable with key `http_proxy` and `ng e2e` ran fine for me.